# Wrapping blocking mpsc in async Rust (Tokio)

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to wrap a synchronous MQTT client [library](https://github.com/AtherEnergy/rumqtt) using Tokio. The code needs to continuously receive messages via  `std::sync::mpsc` channel and send them into the async code.   I understand how to use `spawn_blocking` for wrapping a code that returns a single value. But how this can be applied to wrap a loop that is continuously receiving messages from `std::sync::mpsc` channel?

Here is the code that I use to send messages into the channel.

```
let (mut tx, mut rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut mqtt_options = MqttOptions::new("bot", settings.mqtt.host, settings.mqtt.port);
            let (mut mqtt_client, notifications) = MqttClient::start(mqtt_options).unwrap();

            mqtt_client.subscribe(settings.mqtt.topic_name, QoS::AtLeastOnce).unwrap();

            tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
                println!("Waiting for notifications");
                for notification in notifications {
                    match notification {
                        rumqtt::Notification::Publish(publish) => {
                            let payload = Arc::try_unwrap(publish.payload).unwrap();
                            let text: String = String::from_utf8(payload).expect("Can't decode payload for notification");
                            println!("Recieved message: {}", text);
                            let msg: Message = serde_json::from_str(&text).expect("Error while deserializing message");
                            println!("Deserialized message: {:?}", msg);
                            println!("{}", msg);
                            tx.send(msg);
                        }
                        _ => println!("{:?}", notification)
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

But I am unsure how should I use tokio API to receive these messages inside another async closure.

```
tokio::task::spawn(async move || {
    // How to revieve messages via `rx` here? I can't use tokio::sync::mpsc channels 
    // since the code that sends messages is blocking.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've posted a [separate thread on a rust-lang community](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-wrap-blocking-code-that-returns-multiple-values-in-tokio/40822) and got an answer there.

`std::sync::mpsc::channel` can be swapped to `tokio::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel`, which has a non-async send method. It solves the issue.